# Return the smallest prositive integer > 0

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Referring to the Problem below:

```
That, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

1 Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4. 

2 Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.
```

in given `1` = why does it expect to return 4. how did they come up with 4?

and given `2` = why does it expect to return 1. how did they come up with 1?

When the problem stated o get the positive integer that is greater than 0 `(integer> 0)` where `that does not occur in A.` is ambiguous (i assume it would wants a unique values inside `A`?.

What did i miss?

PS: i failed to read the title which is the `MISSING INTEGER`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pick the smallest positive value of the input array, and then check if the next positive integer is also present in the input array.
If it isn't, return it, if it is present, then check if the next integer is present and so on.

In addition the time complexity is at worst `O(n log(n))` where `n` is the size of the input array as you will never have to increase your initial guess by more than `n` (can't have more than `n` integers in a row), and sorting is  `O(n log(n))`.

Some pseudo code might look like:

```
int findSmallestInt(int[] array) {

  // sort input array

  // check if no positive elements
  if (array[array.size - 1] < 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  int smallestInt = array[0];

  // make sure smallestInt is positive
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size && smallestInt < 0; i++) {
    smallestInt = array[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
    smallestInt += 1;
    if (!array.contains(smallestInt)) {
      return smallestInt;
    }
  }

}
```

In addition, to answer your two questions above:

In 1 it returns 4 as that is the smallest positive integer not present in A, and in 2 it returns 1 as that is the smallest non-zero positive integer not present in A.

Comment: I don’t think your method of picking smallest then searching for the next smallest is `O(nlog(n))`.  You would need to sort the array first, or you’ll get `O(n^2)` worst case.

Comment: @manLaw I agree that it needs to be sorted. There is a comment in my pseudo code that says `sort input array`, but I might need to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution($A) {
    $unique = array_unique($A);
    sort($unique);

    $smallest = false;

    foreach ( $unique as $index => $value ) {
        $prev_index = $index - 1;
        if ( $value > 0 && isset( $unique[ $prev_index ] ) && ( $value - $unique[ $prev_index ] ) > 1 ) {
            $smallest = $unique[ $prev_index ] + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( false === $smallest ) {
        $smallest = max( $unique ) + 1;
    }

    return $smallest;
}
```